# Java Search List by different criteria

Tags: java, generics, search, arraylist

i have several list classes that need to be searched by different criteria (single values, multiple values, etc...). These classes have, at the moment, different methods depending on the search criteria. Since i hate to write the same code again and again i am looking to avoid this... but i don't want to reinvent the wheel.
So, i am considering creating a custom class that implements a generic search.

The code looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ListCustomComparable<T> {

private ArrayList<T> listItems;

public ListCustomComparable() {
}

/**
 * @return the listItems
 */
public ArrayList<T> getListItems() {
    return listItems;
}

/**
 * @param listItems the listItems to set
 */
public void setListItems(ArrayList<T> listItems) {
    this.listItems = listItems;
}

public ArrayList<T> searchByComparable(Comparable<T> comparator){
    ArrayList<T> listRes= new ArrayList<T>();

    for (T item: listItems ){
        if(comparator.equals(item))
            listRes.add(item);
    }

    return listRes;

}
}
```

So, i pretend that every method that wants to do a specific search must implement the comparable interface. This methods, obviously, will need their own code but will rely on the generic class.
Please, what do you think about it? i am reinventing the wheel because it is already done? Or is it OK?

One additional restriction. It should work with 1.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i am reinventing the wheel because it is already done? Or is it OK?

Yes, you are re-inventing the wheel.
What you are suggesting pretty much exactly matches [Predicates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Example {
    static class Person{
        int age;
        String name;

        Person(int age, String name){
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        persons.add(new Person(20,"John"));
        persons.add(new Person(25,"Alice"));
        persons.add(new Person(30,"Peter"));
        persons.add(new Person(25,"Stefan"));


        List<Person> results = persons.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.age <= 25 && p.name.equals("Stefan"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for(Person p : results)
            System.out.println(p.name);

    }
}
```

Predicate is a generic interface that specifies a method that returns a boolean value if something matches or not given that value.

Examples of how predicates can be defined:

```
Predicate<String> filter_1 = str -> "value".equals(str);
Predicate<String> filter_2 = "value"::equals;
Predicate<String> filter_3 = new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) {
        return "value".equals(s);
    }

};

Predicate<String> minLengthFilter = str -> str != null && str.length() > 5;
Predicate<String> maxLengthFilter = str -> str != null && str.length() < 8;
Predicate<String> combined = minLengthFilter.and(maxLengthFilter);
```

In case you have to work with a Java version before 1.8, you could use for example guava[2](https://github.com/google/guava) which also has it's own Predicate[3](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) system.

You could then for example filter it using the Iterables[4](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter(java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate)) class and then finally collect it back in to a list using[5](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList(java.lang.Iterable)).

You could of course find an alternative or make a own function to combine the filter+collect to list methods.

You can also combine Predicates using their Predicates class[6](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html), as well as being able to use them to construct certain simple predicates.

Here's a full example using Guava.

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GuavaExample {
    static class Person{
        int age;
        String name;
        boolean isFemale;

        Person(int age, String name, boolean isFemale){
            this.age = age;
            this.name = name;
            this.isFemale = isFemale;
        }
    }

    public static <T> List<T> applyFilter(List<? extends T> list, Predicate<? super T> ... filters){
        // default case: no filters.
        if (filters == null || filters.length == 0)
            return new ArrayList<T>(list);

        Iterable<? extends T> it = Iterables.filter(list,Predicates.and(filters));
        return Lists.newArrayList(it);
    }

    public static <T> List<T> applyFilter(List<? extends T> list, Predicate<? super T>  filter){
        Iterable<? extends T> it = Iterables.filter(list,filter);
        return Lists.newArrayList(it);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> result;
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

        persons.add(new Person(8, "Little John",false));
        persons.add(new Person(10, "Alice Jnr.",true));
        persons.add(new Person(20,"John",false));
        persons.add(new Person(25,"Alice",true));
        persons.add(new Person(30,"Sarah",true));
        persons.add(new Person(25,"Stefan",false));


        Predicate<Person> isAdult = new Predicate<Person>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Person person) {
                return person.age >= 18;
            }
        };

        Predicate<Person> isFemale = new Predicate<Person>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Person person) {
                return person.isFemale;
            }
        };

        result = applyFilter(persons,isAdult);
        System.out.println("Adults: ");
        for(Person p : result)
            System.out.println(p.name);

        result = applyFilter(persons,Predicates.not(isAdult));
        System.out.println("Children: ");
        for(Person p : result)
            System.out.println(p.name);

        // Generic varargs will yield a warning, unfortionally...
        result = applyFilter(persons, isAdult, isFemale);
        System.out.println("Adult females: ");
        for(Person p : result)
            System.out.println(p.name);
    }
}
```

You could perhaps define the Predicates using functions inside the classes you wish to sort and combine them with other classes that can be used to check if an value matches a certain objective.

e.g.

```
static class Person {
    int age;
    // ... code ...
    public static Predicate<Person> ageFilter(final Range<Integer> range) {
        return new Predicate<Person>() {
            @Override
            public boolean apply(Person person) {
                return range.contains(person.age);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Which can then be re-used for various filters:

```
Predicate<Person> isAdult = Person.ageFilter(Range.atLeast(18)); // Yields 18 and older.
Predicate<Person> isToddler = Person.ageFilter(Range.open(1,3)); // Yields ages 1-3, including 1 and 3 exact.
Predicate<Person> isMiddleAge = Person.ageFilter(Range.openClosed(45,65)); // Yields ages 45-65, 45 included, 65 excluded.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It looks perfect. What i have not said is that i need to work with Java 1.6 and i think lamba expressions needs at least 1.8.

Comment: Updated :) - see the new section/part about guava.